# I want to add class to anchor tag which is in td using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my td:

```
<td width="64%" valign="top" class="addtocart_vak">
<a href="/ShoppingCart.asp?ProductCode=QH1225264">
<img border="0" align="absmiddle" src="btn_addtocart_small.gif">
</a>
</td>
```

I tried next jquery code:

```
$('.addtocart_vak' 'a').addClass("anchor");
```

I also tried next:

```
$(".addtocart_vak a[href$=/ShoppingCart.asp]").addClass("anchor");
```

Please give me correct solution.

**Update:**

I get the following JavaScript Exception:

> [Exception... "'JavaScript component does not have a method named:
>   "onStatusChange"' when calling method:
>   [nsIWebProgressListener::onStatusChange]" nsresult: "0x80570030
>   (NS_ERROR_XPC_JSOBJECT_HAS_NO_FUNCTION_NAMED)" location: ""
>   data: no]

can you give me solution how to fix that error??

Comment: remove ' ' from a & it will work make it like $('.addtocart_vak a')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only provide one string as the selector, but you are breaking your string immediately after the class-selector. You probably get a syntax-error there, right?

If you don't end your selector between the class selector and the tag selector, you will be fine.

Try this instead:

```
$('.addtocart_vak a').addClass("anchor");
```

With this selector (your second attempt):

```
$(".addtocart_vak a[href$=/ShoppingCart.asp]")
```

What you say is give me all `a` elements having an href-attribute that ends with `/ShoppingCart.asp`. *(You should have put quotation-marks around the value though.)* However, since your href-attribute have a querystring, the href-value doesn't end with `/ShoppingCart.asp`. It does however being with that value, so you could have used the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) instead.

```
$(".addtocart_vak a[href^='/ShoppingCart.asp']")
```

**Update:**

The error that you'be shown has nothing to do with jQuery or your selector, but it probably breaks the execution of your script so that your jQuery code doesn't get run. Do you have any ideas on what might be causing that exception? If you fix that, your jQuery-code will probably run fine as well.

Comment: @Monica It should work, here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/S7q3e/) for you. If you inspect the anchor element, you'll see that the achor-class has been added. If it doesn't work for you, the problem probably lie elsewhere. Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: Yes I am getting this Error: [Exception... "'JavaScript component does not have a method named: "onStatusChange"' when calling method: [nsIWebProgressListener::onStatusChange]" nsresult: "0x80570030 (NS_ERROR_XPC_JSOBJECT_HAS_NO_FUNCTION_NAMED)" location: "<unknown>" data: no]

Comment: @Monica You should probably have added that to your question, it would have been much easier for everyone to help you. I added it for you now. That error has nothing to with jQuery or your selector, but it probably breaks the execution of your script so that your jQuery code doesn't get run. Do you have any ideas on what might be causing that exception? If you fix that, your jQuery-code will probably run fine as well.

Comment: @Monica Some quick googeling indicate that this error is caused by a bad firefox extension. Have you tried the code in Chrome for instance?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.addtocart_vak a').addClass("anchor");
```

Or you want the spec the direct child with

```
$('.addtocart_vak > a').addClass("anchor");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an id to your anchor and find it by id or just use

```
$('.addtocart_vak a').addClass("anchor");
```